# Не применяется стиль CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Верстаю сайт. Не могу понять почему не применяется стиль по человечески.
Часть разметки html:

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 922px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 2587px;
  background: #245852;
}

.success_story {
  position: absolute;
  width: 580px;
  height: 158px;
  left: 207px;
  top: 2897px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 157%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <span class="success_story">Let's hear about Kayla's success story</span>
</div>
```

Если span сделать div и применить success_story, все работает.
Что я делаю неправильно? Спасибо

Comment: Наверное ибо span строчный элемент. Дайте ему ```display: block;``` и попробуйте ```display: inline-block;``` (не уверен насчет второго варианта).

Comment: Какой результат хотели получить?

Comment: @OliverPatterson - ваш вариант работает, но к сожалению не совсем так как нужно. Если применить display: block; и удалить position: absolute; то текст уже появляется, но не в том месте где нужно. И поправить его у меня не получается, хотя координаты правильные. Спасибо

Comment: @Pilaton Текст на фоне. То есть background идет просто как фон, span 
 к которому применяется success_story - текст белого цвета на этом же фоне. Но если применить position: absolute; он пропадает, если использовать решение OliverPatterson текст появляется, но не на своем месте, а в углу background. Хотел бы получить текст на фоне в нужном месте. Спасибо

Comment: А зачем вы удаляли position?)

Comment: Кажись понимаю, background ведет себя как relative и у спана идут координаты от него, по этому ```top: 2897px;``` уводит спан за блок.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Правильно ли я понимаю что мне нужно уменьшить top: 2897px ? Но даже если я это делаю то с position ну никак не работает, текст пропадает. Без него так же находится в углу блока. Спасибо

Comment: Если честно, я не понимаю зачем вы прилепили такие огромные диапазоны координат стилям, зачем вот вам такое смещение по высоте `top: 2897px;`?   Если у вас есть макет, или сможете набросать пример того, что вы хотели получить по итогу хотя бы в фотошопе и на листе бумаги, я вам сверстаю с нуля. В данном же случае, я так и не понял что вы хотели получить в конечном результате к сожалению.

Comment: @Oleksandr_Web, текст не пропадает, он находится глубоко внизу, т.к. текст и фон белый - вы его не видите. И да, вам нужно у спана уменьшить top.

Comment: @Pilaton Да тут лендинг такой длинный, по сути это уже второй экран как бы идет. Большое спасибо за советы разобрался

Comment: @OliverPatterson Таки да, текст есть, большое спасибо вам за помощь! С вашей помощью разобрался в проблеме, текст просто слишком сильно уехал в низ. Спасибо еще раз!